# What’s the deal with “fariĝi”?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-formation

In a lot of places I see the word *fariĝi* when, from context, it seems that the speaker/writer just meant *iĝi* (to become). For example: «Mi studas por (far)iĝi kuracisto.»

Why is the radical *far-* used here at all? It doesn’t seem to fit. It would literally mean “to become done” or “to become doing”, which is nonsensical.

If the idea is that *iĝi* is merely a suffix and shouldn’t be seen as a word in its own right, then wouldn’t *estiĝi* be a more suitable construction than *fariĝi*? But if this is the rationale, then why doesn’t the same apply to *ejo*, *ulo*, *ilo*, *ege* and others that I see a lot more?

Comment: Mi ankaux reagis tiel kiam mi eklernis! Mi antauxgxojas ricevi respondon.

Answer (score 4):

Attached to a transitive root, the suffixoid -*iĝi* detransitivizes it, this means the verb gets the meaning of a passive or of a reflexive: *ruli* 'to roll (something)' - *ruliĝi* 'to roll oneself, to be rolled, to roll (intr.)'

So *fariĝi* means 'to be made into something' or 'to make oneself into something'. There is a slight difference in meaning to mere *iĝi*, which means 'to become' (without an overt causer), but it will be hard to find a context where this would be of importance, especially as *fariĝi* may also be generalized to an extent where it means 'to become' without thinking of any causer.

With intransitive or stative roots like *esti* 'to be' *iĝi* means 'to become': *sidi* 'to sit' - *sidiĝi* 'to sit down'.

So *estiĝi* means 'to become being', which is actually identical to 'to become'.

You ask why in such cases there is a root before *iĝi* at all, as they don't add real information. This has historical reasons, as in the early stage of the language the affixoids were used as standalone words much less often than today, certainly by the influence of European (and other) languages, who don't know affixoids, but much more strictly distinguish between standalone words and bound affixes. The evolution of the "liberation" of affixoids in Esperanto is a slow process, for instance suffixoid *isto* 'professional' still today is hardly used as a root.

Answer (score 1):

I'm curious how you learned Esperanto? In my experience, the Duolingo course puts too strong an emphasis on suffixes (including *iĝi*) as free-standing words -- although both *iĝi* and *fariĝi* are used in the course.

Both these words mean the same thing. There's no difference in meaning between *iĝi* and *fariĝi*. When in doubt, though, use *fariĝi* - that is, follow the advice of Jordan in Being Colloqual in Esperanto and use *fariĝi* because it's more colloquial and less jarring.

***Fari*** means "to make, do" (*faru lin kvieta*) - so *fariĝi* means the same thing except that "lin" becomes the subject (*Li fariĝu kvieta*). This doesn't work with *estas* because there is no object.

As for *ejo, ulo, ilo, ege* and others, there are a few explanations - one of which boils down to tradition. At the same time, people do use words like *loko, persono,* and *tre* all the time. You can certainly use *iĝi* if you want to - and many people do. Many speakers (myself included) have a stylistic preference for *fariĝi*.

Comment: I use _fariĝi_ simply because it is more common, however, I had the same reaction as OP when I was learning, and I didn't learn from Duolingo, but from Montagu C. Butler's book about 12 years ago. I haven't looked at the Duolingo course very much but I think the use of affixes as standalone words has been a growing trend for a while and I see no problem with it. I think _iĝi_ is the more logical word and I wouldn't be phased by it, but it would definitely give off a "modern" vibe to me, versus reading _fariĝi_ which would come across as "traditional" or even (slightly) old-fashioned.

Comment: I did not know that *fari* also means *igi* (but according to ReVo it does; sense #2). I don’t think I’ve ever seen it used that way; I’ve only seen it used in the sense *agi* (ReVo #3) and perhaps sometimes *krei* (ReVo #1). Given that, it shouldn’t be surprising that *fariĝi* appeared nonsensical to me.

Comment: P.S. I do not understand the stylistic preference for *fariĝi*, especially if you agree that *iĝi* means the same thing, implying that the extra radiko *far-* is redundant and unnecessary. It’s much clearer without.

Comment: Just to note in case the answer gave a misleading impression, _estiĝi_ does also exist and it has the definition “iĝi estanta” en PIV. You can find it in Zamenhof’s translation of the bible: “per la vorto de la Eternulo estiĝis la ĉielo”. I don’t think it’s particularly rare even in modern usage.

Comment: Three comments: (1) Timwi - I think stylistic preferences are difficult to explain. Often the answer is "just 'cos" or (as I said in my answer) "tradition." (2) Neil Roberts - thanks for the comment on *estiĝi*. I brushed over the details in my reply, quite frankly because I couldn't remember them and couldn't be bothered to track them down because they were beside my point - but I think your clarification here is useful. (3) There are reasons that Duolingo put an even stronger emphasis on suffixes-as-words beyond any possible trend but this has been discussed in another question.

Answer (score 0):

- igxi = to become
- farigxi = to become something as a result of doing something

> Logic will be on your side if you use iĝi, but you will be speaking
>   more colloquial Esperanto if you use fariĝi. http://pages.ucsd.edu/~dkjordan/eo/colloq/colloq120.html#sec12-4-10