Kie povas mi enmeti 'tro'-n en ĉi tia konstruaĵo inkludanta '-iĝi'?
Mi ripete trovas ke konsekvence al nia emo por uzi adjektivon+iĝi anstataŭ fariĝi+adjektivon kiel antaũe, mi ne scias kie enmeti adverbojn. Ekzemple, se mi volas diri: "la du sonoj (fari)ĝis tro similaj" mi emas preference diri: "la du sonoj tro similiĝis". Sed mi vere ne ŝatas la fluon de la frazo.
Ĉu eĉ enmeto de tro antaŭ de verbo estas gramatika? Mi povus aldoni tro multe sed mi volas lerni se tiu estas la sola solvo.

Kial "fariĝi"? ... "iĝi" sufiĉas. "La du sonoj iĝis tro similaj".

Kvankam via propono funkcias mia demando estas fokusita je la frazo enhavanta "similiĝis". Ŝanĝo de fariĝi al iĝi estas nur kosmetikaĵo tiamaniere ke mi ne stumblas pro ĝi

Kelkaj faras distingon inter "fariĝi" kaj "iĝi", sed tio ne estas norma uzo.

Estas neniu kialo eviti "fariĝi/iĝi + adjektivo". Tio estas la plej klara maniero por montri, pri kio temas. Cetere tiam vi ne havas vian problemon kien enmeti la vorteton "tro". Notu, ke ĉi-okaze vi ankaŭ povus uzi la verbon "ŝanĝiĝi" aŭ "La du sonoj ŝanĝiĝis al tro similaj".

Ho, mi ne sciis tion. Mi trovis fantastajn kialojn de tiu kiu vi diras je https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/3174/what-s-the-deal-with-fari%C4%9Di. Certe estas subtila ŝanĝo de signifo nepre ne semantika por la plejparto de Esperantujo; sed mi ne rimarkus ĝin neregula.

Dankon, sed via ekzemplo nur burĝonigas novajn demandojn. Vi uzas 'al tro'. Ŝajne forĵetante la finan nomon ("sonoj"). Vi pravas ke ĉi tiuj alternativoj estas sufiĉe bona por esprimi mian intencon. Malgraŭ, mia demando pri adverboj, kiu modifas la verbon, daŭras.


Ekzemple, se mi volas diri: "la du sonoj (fari)ĝis tro similaj" mi
emas preference diri: "la du sonoj tro similiĝis". Sed mi vere ne
ŝatas la fluon de la frazo.

La du frazoj estas samsignifaj, sed la unua estas pli komprenebla.
